# Have multiple enums as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a page were you can see all the F1 drivers with there stats and there characteristics.
With that last one I'm having some trouble...

Pilot.cs

```
public class Pilot
{
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public TeamNames TeamName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int Podiums { get; set; }
    public int Championships { get; set; }
    public int GrandsPrix { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public Characteristic Characteristics { get; set; }
}
```

PilotRepository.cs

```
public class PilotRepository
{
    protected static Pilot[] Pilots =
    {
        new Pilot
        {
            SurName = "Hamilton",
            FirstName = "Lewis",
            TeamName = TeamNames.Mercedes,
            Image = "hamilton.jpg",
            Podiums = 151,
            Championships = 6,
            GrandsPrix = 250,
            Points = 3431,
            Characteristics = Characteristic.WorldClass | Characteristic.Consistency | Characteristic.Veteran
        },
        new Pilot
        {
            SurName = "Bottas",
            FirstName = "Valtteri",
            TeamName = TeamNames.Mercedes,
            Image = "bottas.jpg",
            Podiums = 45,
            Championships = 0,
            GrandsPrix = 140,
            Points = 1289,
            Characteristics = Characteristic.WorldClass | Characteristic.Consistency | Characteristic.Veteran
        }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Pilot> GetPilots()
    {
        return Pilots;
    }
}
```

Characteristic.cs

```
[Flags]
public enum Characteristic
{
    [Display(Name = "World Class")]
    WorldClass,
    [Display(Name = "Future star")]
    FutureStar,
    [Display(Name = "Agressive driver")]
    AgressiveDriver,
    Consistency,
    [Display(Name = "Crash master")]
    CrashMaster,
    Modest,
    Veteran,
    [Display(Name = "Epic battles")]
    EpicBattles,
    [Display(Name = "Early retirements")]
    EarlyRetirements,
    Overtaker,
    Rookie,
    [Display(Name = "Last of the pack")]
    LastOfThePack
}
```

Now when I show them in my views I only get the first and last one.
Or in some cases I get totally different ones than the ones that I gave in.
Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: What you are missing are *values* specified for each enumeration item, assigning each of them the actual bit value. See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Try specificing the values of the enum flags with powers of 2

Comment: In your repo class. The driver can have more than one characteristic?